# Unobtrusive Jquery autocomplete rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a railsCombobox() plugin that I have implemented...it actually connects to an input HTML tag like the following:

```
$('input[id=box1]').railsCombobox();
```

My question:

I have many inputs with ids ranging from box1 to box5 that I want to append this plugin to, what would be the easiest and most efficient way to do so. Should I use a loop? or is there a special piece of code that can take care of that easily?

Many thanks.

Edit:
This is my javascript plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input[data-ddcombobox]').railsCombobox();
});

(function( jQuery ){
    var self = null;
    $.fn.railsCombobox =  function(){
        if(!this.railsAutoCompleter){
            this.railsAutoCompleter = new jQuery.railsCombobox(this);
        }
    //  this.init(this)
    }/*function() {
        return this.live('focus', function(){
            if(!this.railsAutoCompleter){
                this.railsAutoCompleter = new jQuery.railsCombobox(this);
            }
        });
    };*/
    jQuery.railsCombobox = function(e){
        _e = e;
        this.init(_e);
    };
    jQuery.railsCombobox.fn = jQuery.railsCombobox.prototype = {
        railsCombobox: '0.0.1'
    };  
    jQuery.railsCombobox.fn.extend = jQuery.railsCombobox.extend = jQuery.extend;
    jQuery.railsCombobox.fn.extend({
        init: function(e){
            e.delimiter = $(e).attr('data-delimiter') || null;
            function split( val ){
                return val.split( e.delimiter );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
                return split( term ).pop().replace(/^\s+/,"");
            }
            $(e).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response){
                    $.getJSON( $(e).attr('data-ddcombobox'), {
                        term: extractLast(request.term)
                        }, response );
                    },
                search: function(){
                    // cusom minLength
                    var term = this.value;
                },
                focus: function(){
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ){
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma and space at the end
                    if(e.delimiter != null){
                        term.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(e.delimiter);
                    }else{
                        this.value = terms.join("");
                        if($(this).attr('id_element')){
                            $($(this).attr('id_element')).val(ui.item.id);
                        }
                    };
                    return false;
                }
            });
            ////////////
            this.button = $( "<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .insertAfter(e)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visibl
                    if($(e).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")){
                        $(e).autocomplete("close");
                    }else{ 
                        if($(e).val()==""){
                            $(e).autocomplete('search', " ");
                        }else{
                            $(e).autocomplete('search', $(e).val());
                        }
                    }
                });
            ////////////
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [# selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for ids. The best approach though is to assign your inputs the same class like `autocomplete`

```
<input id="box1" class="autocomplete" type="text" />
```

You can then just do

```
$('.autocomplete').railsCombobox();
```

**UPDATE**

Your problem with the plugin is caused by your click handler

```
.click(function() {
    // close if already visibl
    if($(e).autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")){
        $(e).autocomplete("close");
    }else{ 
        if($(e).val()==""){
            $(e).autocomplete('search', " ");
        }else{
            $(e).autocomplete('search', $(e).val());
        }
    }
});
```

You're working with e which is all of the objects you passed in. In this case all of the input fields. I would open up another question regarding how to fix your plugin.

Comment: If I do so, all the plugins have the same id for some weird reason. So basically my combobox() involves a button and if I click it, all the comboboxes on the page respond to the click.

Comment: @Mahmoud, Are you assigning a different id for each input? I'm not sure how your plugin works, are you creating this button or is it hard coded into the plugin. If it's the latter then yes they will all respond to it.

Comment: It's indeed hardcoded in my plugin, how could that be solved?

Comment: I made an Edit with my detailed plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a class to all input and use class selector

eg

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="box1"  class="myPlugin" />
<input type="text" name="box2"  class="myPlugin" />
<input type="text" name="box3"  class="myPlugin" />
```

**js**

```
jQuery('.myPlugin').railsCombobox();
```